# How to set anchor point manually for popoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am having problems trying to use a `popoverPresentationController`, basically I have two views and one has a popover segue segue to another. However the second view controller requires an Anchor point, but the first view controller I set the `bavigationBar` right button items manually in the view did load, because I needed more than one button.

So I added a right bar button item in the storyboard and set the anchor to that, but then the `PopoverViewController`appears in the top left and this isn't practical because when segueing it shows the bar button item then changes to the button items I add manually.

So I removed the text from the button and just added some empty space; now I get no errors but the popover appears in the top left not top right.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can set the anchor point when segueing or before the popover is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

If you override your view controller's `prepareForSegue`, you get a chance to alter the viewController you are about to segue to before it is shown.

It is called before viewDidLoad is called on it, so you can't do anything with the outlets.  Usually just set some property that can be looked at later.